# What are the Benefits Of Death According to the Will of God?

Tags: word-study

What are the benefits of death to believers according to the Apostle John's writings in the New Testament?

Comment: All CAPS? Really?

Comment: I know the question was limited to John's writings, but there is more in other parts of the Old and New Testaments.

Answer (score 2):

Rest : "And I heard a voice from heaven saying, “Write this: Blessed are the dead who die in the Lord from now on.” “Blessed indeed,” says the Spirit, “that they may rest from their labors, for their deeds follow them!”  Revelation 14:13 ESV

Comment: Question was closed, but good answer